# angular uib-carousel, active slide not working

Tags: carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like something as simple as displaying a selected index from the carousel slide. But for some reason it doesn't work.

The documentation is kinda cryptic so i'm not sure if I do it correctly.
Here is my html (Note: there is some flask | ninja inside it, what is important here is the active="slide.active"):

```
 <uib-carousel id="over" active="active" interval="myInterval" no-wrap="noWrapSlides" ng-swipe-left="next()" ng-swipe-right="prev()">
    <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by slide.id" index="slide.id" active="slide.active">
      <a href="{{url_for('display_keetle_detail')}}">
        <img class="irmg" ng-src="{{slide.image|angular}}" style="margin:auto;" ng-click="test(slide.id)">
      </a>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      </div>
    </uib-slide>
  </uib-carousel>
```

So my carrousel is working. But for example, from my js, I would like to display the 3th index:

```
 $scope.slides[3].active = true;
```

Where slides is an array of slide. From the documentation it says that it make the slide 'active'. I'm not sure if it means that making it active will display it as the current slide of the carousel as I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active value on the uib-carousel directive is used to manage which uib-slide directive index value is active. Since slide.id is the index value of the slides, you would need to use: `$scope.active = slides[3].id`.

Comment: Thanks that works. Can I ask you how did you know how to set the expected value with the right type this way? I just re-read the documentation, and could never assume it should be done like that. Thank you anyway

Comment: From the docs in the uib-carousel settings section: active - Index of current active slide.  The eye icon indicates a 2 way binding on that property.  The tab directive works the same way.  If the description can be improved, please open an issue and offer a suggestion.